# Adding Rows from one table to Another Table based on days of month SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named Students having 10 records of students

```
ID StudentName
1   Student a
2   Student b
-   ------  -
10  Student N
```

now i want to add these 10 students to another table based on days of month e.g

```
ID StudentName DayOfMonth
1  Student a        1
2  Student a        2
-  ---------        -
-  Student a        31
-  Student b         1
-  ------- b         31
```

And for all the students is there any SQL dynamic Solution
I tried using Cursor but it takes approx 2 minutes if there are 55 Students in a table. While I checked the table during execution of proc it generate **1705 rows** i.e **(55x31)** in a matter of seconds but than it reacts as it is hanged or something and after 2 minutes it shows the success message.
any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
@fkStudentID int,
@fkClassID int,
@fkSessionID int,
@Dated date,

AS
Declare @Days  as  int
Set @Days = DAY(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1,@Dated),0)))
Declare @OffSet as int
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @MyField int;
BEGIN
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
select fkStudentID from dbo.tblAdmission
    where fkClassID = @fkClassID and fkSessionID = @fkSessionID 

OPEN @MyCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
   INTO @MyField 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    While(@OffSet <= @Days)
    Begin

        if(IsNull((Select count(RegisterID) from tblRegister where @MyField = fkStudentID and fkClassID = @fkClassID and fkSessionID = @fkSessionID and [Dayofmonth] = @OffSet),0) = 0)
        Begin
            Insert into tblRegister (fkStudentID, fkClassID, fkSessionID, [DayOfMonth], Dated) values (@MyField, @fkClassID, @fkSessionID, @OffSet, DATEADD(DAY, (@OffSet - 1), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
        End
        Set @OffSet = @OffSet + 1
    End
    Set @OffSet = 1
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
  INTO @MyField 

END; 

CLOSE @MyCursor ;
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

Comment: It is a challenge for us to help troubleshoot your code without seeing it. Post the proc code along with table DDL. I would expect a set-based Cartesian product (cross join) query to run under a second. Do you have any triggers on the table?

Comment: Please check procedure code as above

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you see a delay before the proc ends but it is best to use a set-based query instead of cursor whenever possible for best performance. I expect the example below will run in less than a second as long as you have appropriate indexes (ideally, a unique clustered index on dbo.tblAdmission fkClassID and fkSessionID columns and a unique index on dbo.tblRegister fkStudentID, fkClassID, fkSessionID, and DayOfMonth).

```
CREATE PROC dbo.Example
    @fkClassID int,
    @fkSessionID int,
    @Dated date
AS

INSERT INTO dbo.tblRegister
    (
      fkStudentID
    , fkClassID
    , fkSessionID
    , DayOfMonth
    , Dated
    ) 
SELECT
      a.fkStudentID
    , a.fkClassID
    , a.fkSessionID
    , o.offset
    , DATEADD(DAY, (o.offset - 1), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '', GETDATE()), ''))
FROM dbo.tblAdmission AS a
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
                ,(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)
                ,(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31)) AS o(offset)
WHERE
    a.fkClassID =  @fkClassID 
    AND a.fkSessionID = @fkSessionID
    AND o.offset <= DAY(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1,@Dated),0)))
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.tblRegister AS r
        WHERE
            r.fkStudentID = a.fkStudentID 
            AND r.fkClassID = a.fkClassID
            AND r.fkSessionID = a.fkSessionID
            AND [Dayofmonth] = o.offset
        );
```

Comment: Thx Dan much appreciated looks good to me one thing value of days of month is harcoded in some cases you know it can be different depending on month.